# Java Netty 5 ByteBuf to String the right way

Tags: java

Hi so i started using Netty a couple of days ago but i noticed that the way am converting the ByteBuf to String is using lot's of memory each time its used

Is there any other way to do this with out using lots of memory?

By the way CheckPacket function is a simple if string contains.

Thx.

```
    ByteBuf byteBuffer=(ByteBuf)msg;
    byte[] result = new byte[byteBuffer.readableBytes()];
    byteBuffer.readBytes(result).retain();
    String resultStr = new String(result);
    if (!resultStr.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(resultStr);
        CheckPacket(resultStr, client);
    }
    byteBuffer.release();
    byteBuffer.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

This example may help you:

```
        byte[] inputBytes;
        int offset = 0;
        int length = input.readableBytes();
        if (input.hasArray()) {
            inputBytes = input.array();
            offset = input.arrayOffset() + input.readerIndex();
        } else {
            inputBytes = new byte[length];
            input.getBytes(input.readerIndex(), inputBytes);
        }
```

Full source [here](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client/blob/bbd08078d651ddf433274f4044cacb8a1e7b6915/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/java/transcoder/JsonArrayTranscoder.java).

Answer (score 0):

You might get help from [code.openhub.net](http://code.openhub.net/file?fid=iCKo66-NR1NalYwOoqY7QGBjUIM&cid=feVljZSszT4&s=Java%20Netty%205%20ByteBuf%20to%20String%20the%20right%20way&fp=402676&mp,=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&projSelected=true#L0):

```
driveableType = ByteBufUtils.readUTF8String(data);
driveableData = new DriveableData(ByteBufUtils.readTag(data));
initType(getDriveableType(), true);
```